# Can I book a seat on the Glacier Express from Zermatt to Disentis?

Tags: trains, bookings, switzerland

I want to take the Glacier Express from Zermatt and disembark at Disentis.

However, on http://www.glacierexpress.ch/, when I select Zermatt as my starting point, my destinations are limited to the following:

[image: Limited destination list]

Note that this leg isn't mentioned on the [Glacier Express ticket price list](http://www.glacierexpress.ch/EN/timetable_tickets/Tickets_prices/Pages/default.aspx) either.

Am I able to book this leg? If so, how?

**Edit #1:** Further to my original question, is there any difficulty disembarking at Disentis after buying a longer ticket to Chur? Note that I'll have a few suitcases with me.

**Edit #2:** Per [Andrew Lazarus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/18431/andrew-lazarus)' post, this particular segment of the Glacier Express route can be booked on sbb.ch (option 1 in the screenshot in Andrew's response). The first class fare is CHF 153, as opposed to CHF 204 for Zermatt -> Chur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though this is on a private railway, you may buy the ticket at the SBB-CFF-FSS [site](http://bahn.ch). (That’s three acronyms in German, French, and Italian for the one Swiss State Railways.) Choice of language is in tiny letters near the top of the screen.

I have just checked, and I could have booked Zermatt-Disentis by either the Express or a combination of local trains.

The following screenshot shows the availability of the GEX ticket from Zermatt, disembarking at Disentis:
[image: sbb.ch Zermatt to Disentis]

Comment: You are right! Thank you for trying this. I will add a screenshot of the offering on sbb.ch to my original post for reference.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Glacier Express' is a special kind of train, more of a tourist attraction than a transport service and [the sales manual](https://www.matterhorngotthardbahn.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/MGBahn/Dateien/SalesManual/2015/MGB_September_2015_en_WEB.pdf) suggests that only certain segments can be booked.

One option would be to book a longer segment that you actually want. Alternatively, if you are happy to travel on just a train rather than the 'Glacier Express', you could take the ordinary trains which run on the same route, which run hourly. The tradeoff is that it would take 5 hours instead of 4 and you would have to change trains twice. I think it should also be cheaper. You can see these connections [by searching here](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/) and using the advanced search to restrict the result to 'R' trains only.

Comment: I do prefer the faster route, with fewest transfers possible. Is there any difficulty disembarking at Disentis after buying a longer ticket? I'll add this to my original question, too.